# How to render a Google App Engine template?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know you can render a template by using something like:

```
    template_values = {
        'contacts': contacts,
        'url': url,
        'url_linktext': url_linktext,
    }

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')        
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

My question is, how would I render a template ('addcontact.html) if it's just a simple form used to capture data?

Thanks!

Comment: just remove the template_values & replace index.html to the addcontact.html , template_values is used to pass data to the template when needed

Comment: @Saif al Harthi: That's incorrect. That gives me an error that says the render() method accepts two parameters, not one.

Comment: sorry i forgot in the template_values just put this {} , very sorry , so it will be template.render(path , {})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the template.render accept 2 arguments , when there is no values to pass just use this {}

so it will be template.render(templatefile , {})

Comment: Of course, if you're really "rendering" something that doesn't need any template values substituted, you're probably better off just using a static HTML file and not having a handler for it at all...

Comment: he was using the simple steps provided by google :) , you are right but its good for him to know